# How to add an array to a key in nsdictionary

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I want to add an array to a key in nsdictionary. Such as each key is a question and each questions has multiple answers.

Question1 = [Answer1], [Answer2] , [Answer3];

Question2 = [Answer1], [Answer2] , [Answer3];

With below code I get **No Visible @interface for NSDictionary declares the selector 'setObject:forKey:'**

```
//answers
_surveyAnswers1 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSArray *myArrayAnswers1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"One",@"Two", nil];
NSArray *myArrayAnswers2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Three",@"Four", nil];
[_surveyAnswers1 setObject:myArrayAnswers1 forKey:@"FirstKey"];
[_surveyAnswers1 setObject:myArrayAnswers2 forKey:@"SecondKey"];
```

What is correct way to add an array to a key in NSDictionary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`_surveyAnswers1` seems to be declared as an `NSDictionary`:

```
NSDictionary * _surveyAnswers1;
```

You need to declare it as `NSMutableDictionary`:

```
NSMutableDictionary * _surveyAnswers1;
```

The compiler checks what methods are available on the object based on its declared type; `NSDictionary` does not have the method `setObject:forKey:`, so the compiler warns you (under ARC, this is an error) about that. It would work at runtime, because the object *actually is* an `NSMutableDictionary`, but you should still fix the declaration.

Comment: yes you are right, forgot to change NSDictionary * _surveyAnswers1; to NSDictionary * _surveyAnswers1;  at @property

Answer (score 2):

Although you are instantiating _surveyAnswers1 as an NSMutableDictionary, it's declared as an NSDictionary type so either change _surveyAnswers1 to be NSMutableDictionary type or cast _surveyAnswers1 to NSMutableDictionary when you call setObject:forKey:

```
[((NSMutableDictionary *)_surveyAnswers1) setObject:myArrayAnswers1 forKey:@"FirstKey"];
[((NSMutableDictionary *)_surveyAnswers1) setObject:myArrayAnswers2 forKey:@"SecondKey"];
```